# Firebase Storage on Safari Mobile giving storage/unknown error

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, safari, firebase-storage

I am currently working on a Progressive Web App that runs mainly on mobile. I tested it on iOS, but when I tried to upload an image to Firebase Storage (via Safari), it has the error: storage/unknown. This error does not occur in chrome.

Here is the related code (this snippet will not run, because it is not connected to firebase or the file it comes from):

```js
let imageRef = storage.child(`images/${fileName}`);

    let task = imageRef.put(image);
    task.on('state_changed',
        function progress(snapshot) {
            $('#uploadProgress').show(); // this is a progress bar
            let percent = 50; // a testing value
            $('#uploadProgress').val(percent);
        },
        function error(err) {
            console.log(err.code);
        },
        function complete() {
            // This runs unrelated code
        }
    );
```

My security rules are

```
`service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}`
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this ?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: I am getting many errors from iOS and Safari, while in Android/Chrome everything works great.